# Java virtual restricted storage (virtual disk, image, encrypted zip file, whatever...)

Tags: java, zip, containers, storage, assets

I am developing a system that would operate with a repository (directory) of files.
Users would be allowed to operate with these files via a systems's client but not directly via file explorer, which means I need to somehow hide/restrict access.

I thought about storing all files inside some kind of encrypted package and when a user wants to access a file, extract/decrypt it and provide it's information. Something similar to what games do with their proprietary container formats. Is there any standard solution for this kind of task? I do not want to reinvent a wheel.

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources (such books/tutorials, tools/libraries) are off-topic here.

Comment: @GhostCat I'm not asking to compare and define "the best". It a question and it has a definite answer but I was unable to find one.

Comment: Therefore I only put up that comment, but didnt downvote your question.

Comment: @GhostCat I read the rules, I really did, but I see this kind of questions every day so I assume they are perfectly valid for this side. After all, where else would a software dev ask these? On reddit maybe? Google fails miserably when you are looking for something you do not fully understand and/or lack proper terminology.

Comment: Again: I am only pointing out that the part about asking for "solutions" is grey area. Beyond that: the absence of *other* places to ask certain things is not an argument to put up content here that would be offtopic. Maybe you are lucky, and you get a good technical answer, maybe you are not. All I am saying is that people *might* have objections here.